# Is it possible to extract the Adsense publisher ID of a youtube channel / video page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube, youtube-api, adsense

I faced this when I was researching google support methods.
say that you are a content creator or the owner of a `YouTube` channel that shows ads, and somehow you lost your access to your AdSense publisher ID
just for the sake of the argument.
We know that you can get the AdSense Publisher ID of a normal webpage
simply by looking at the page source code, and it's there loud and clear.
but it seems a bit tricky to get a `YouTube` channel AdSense publisher ID, it's as if `YouTube` is masking this piece of information,
is it so, or am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Can you provide an example of where you have to look? Such as a Youtube channel or wherever you are looking

Answer (score 3):

You want to know the Adsense ID of user-owned current YouTube Channel. All you need is view source the video page and find **ca-yt-host-pub** if current youtube video has permission to run google ad.

I will come up with **ca-yt-host-pub-[adsenseid]**.

If video or youtube channel is not eligible for google ads you will not find any entry for same.

Comment: I tried that before posting the question but that number seems to be the same on multiple channels offering ads so it can't be the publisher ID..
do you have a youtube channel showing ads? have you test it on your own channel?

Comment: For which channel you want to reproduce I too checked for multiple accounts and its working fine.

Let me know the youtube channel URL.

Comment: this is not the publisher ID this is what youtube creates to mask the publisher ID
sort of a linked ID